# Asynchrounous caching data; (Begin/End)ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, asynchronous, caching

I have a static method in which I hope to cache all the data I require for the functioning of my WPF application.

```
public static async Task CacheAllAsync() { ... }
```

Now, to cache the data, I have dedicated caching methods around project in each model, of which I need to cache the data. Something like this:

```
public static void CacheAuthObjects( IAsyncResult result )
{
    SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand) result.AsyncState;
    SqlDataReader dbr = cmd.EndExecuteReader( result );

    try
    {
        while ( dbr.Read() )
        {
            CachedData.AuthObjs.Add( new AuthObj( dbr ) );
        }
        dbr.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        // log; send email to admin...
    }
}
```

and I use this method in my 'CacheAllAsync' method like this:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand( "SELECT ...." );
cmd.Connection = Engine.CreateDefaultDBConnection();
await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();
cmd.BeginExecuteReader( AuthObjectDB.CacheAuthObjects, cmd );
```

The First issue I have here is that I don't know when the operation is complete. I found some examples online on using 'BeginExecuteReader', but they will only say that you need to use 'EndExecuteReader', not showing exactly how.

The objective here is to start multiple `BeginExecuteReader`'s (I am guessing around 10 or 15 of them) and have them all tell me when they are finished, so I can update my GUI when the last one is complete. So, bear in mind I need my `CacheAllAsync` method to return the task when the last dedicated caching method has finished.

P.S.
I would also appreciate if you tell me this is not a good approach and how would I go about improving it. Maybe to put all these 10-15 separated threads in only one, as a queue, and have them wait for each other? That would be slower, but safer and less CPU consuming, I guess, so I would prefer the first approach.

Comment: I think you should base your solution on `Task.Run`, `Task.WhenAll` and `ExecuteReaderAsync`.

Comment: Okay, if I am not using `BeginExecuteReader` and `EndExecuteReader`, my dedicated caching methods don't have to be asynchronous, right? I just create a task out of it and add it to a list, start them all and await them. So, can I just use `ExecuteReader`? I'll add an answer with code, to explain it better.

Answer (score -1):

This is just another try of getting to my objective. What do you make of this?

I put the rest of the logic ( connection string, command and openning the connection ) for caching each model list in its dedicated method, like this:

```
public static bool CacheAuthObjects( )
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "SELECT ..." );
    cmd.Connection = Engine.CreateDefaultDBConnection();

    cmd.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader dbr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
        while ( dbr.Read() )
        {
            CachedData.AuthObjects.Add( new AuthObject( dbr ) );
        }
        dbr.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        // log, send mail..
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I use `ExecuteReader` now. And I am creating a `Task` out of this method, put it in a list, start all of the tasks and await them, all in the main caching method, like this:

```
public static async Task<bool> CacheAllAsync()
{
    // creating the list for the tasks
    List<Task<bool>> cachingTasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

    // adding the task
    cachingTasks.Add( new Task<bool>(AuthObjectDB.CacheAuthObjects ) );

    // ... adding the rest of the tasks....

    // starting the tasks
    foreach ( Task t in cachingTasks )
        t.Start();

    // awaiting the tasks to complete
    Task<bool[]> task = Task.WhenAll( cachingTasks );
    await task;

    // checking if any of the tasks failed to complete
    foreach ( bool b in task.Result )
        if ( !b ) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Ivan, did you mean something like this? I like this even more, since the logic is spread more evenly. I guess you suggested `ExecuteReader` if I were to read the data inside od the main caching method. Or am I doing something wrong? The code is actually working well, the UI is responsive and the data is being loaded.

Comment: The core problem here is async I/O.  Task.Start (or task.Run) is using parallelism to solve the job, very wasteful in worker threads. Not such a problem on a WPF client but this would be a disaster on an ASP.NET  service.

Comment: I did some benchmarking with executing tasks in series and in parallel. Multiple threads have virutally no effect on the cpu and ram usage (those were simple tasks after all and I was testing with only 5 of them), but it is ~twice as fast to run them parallel. Thank you for the comment, but I guess I will be sticking to this approach.

Comment: Why downvote, Henk? And why did you delete your answer?